# Office (Outlook) Interop Issue on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, automation, interop, ms-office, windows-server-2008-r2

I made a small Console Application that sends a SMS.
As you maybe know, you can send SMS with Outlook.

Well I finished and everything worked fine, but only on my Desktop PC with Windows 7.

On the machine where I really need it and where it should be installed it doesn't work!

It's a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.

I found a [Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us) about, that Office Automation is not "recommended" with Servers and that it "won't work well".

In my case it's a requirement and I must get it work somehow.

Here the Code to send SMS:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
var sms = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMobileItemSMS);
//Unnecessary Things between I removed
sms.Send(true);
```

The error I get is the following:

> Operation aborted {Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)}

For any working solution or help I'm deeply grateful!

Comment: It's a dumb question but I have to ask, is Outlook definitely installed on the server? If so, are you running this process manually while physically logged into the server? Or is it being run by a website or a service, basically not being run by an interactive user?

Comment: fixed the problem, pretty strange though - look my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

Little bit strange but changing Platform target in the Build Tab from "**ANY CPU**" to "**x86**" made the application successfully work/run on the windows server.

Maybe this can help others too :)